# Why is $(.5, 1]$ considered an open set in $[0, 1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Why is $(.5, 1]$ considered an open set in $[0, 1]$? This is from a topology textbook.

Comment: $(.5,1]=(.5,a)\cap [0,1]$ with $a>1$.

Comment: Because its complement is closed :) (The other comments and answers speak to the real answer to your question.)

Comment: Do you know what can be called as an *open set* in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @alex.jordan I thought about that but wasn't sure if it was true in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a topological space, and $S\subseteq X$ is any subset of $X$. Then the [subspace topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) on $S$ consists of
$$\{U\subseteq S\mid\exists\text{ an open }V\subseteq X\text{ such that }U=V\cap S\}$$
So take $X=\mathbb{R}$, and $S=[0,1]$. Can you think of an open subset $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $V\cap S=(0.5,1]$?

Answer (score 4):

The open sets on a subspace $ S \subseteq X$ are simply the $ U \cap S,$ where $U$ is any open set of $X.$ In this case, $X$ is the real line, the interval $(1/2,3)$ is an open set in $X,$ and the intersection with $S = [0,1]$ is therefore open in the subspace topology. It is likely to be worth your time to show that this definition does give a topology on a subset.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of $[0,1]$ as a metric space, with the usual metric restricted to it, then your set is the open ball (in the metric space $[0,1]$) of radius $0.5$ with center $1$.  Open balls are open sets.